# Get Filtered List from BindingListView

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForm project I have a datagridview with a `BindingListView<Product>` as the source using [Andrew Davey's BindingListView implementation](http://blw.sourceforge.net/). I have used this to filter the grid using other controls. In my presenter class I want to be able to loop through the products that are currently filtered for and update them to a new value.

However it seems that BindingListView does not have any method to get the filtered List, so the following code just returns all the products, not just the ones visible in the grid.

Is there a way without having to loop through the DataGridView rows, to get the visible products?

```
foreach (Product product in bindingListView)
  {
      UpdateViewCellValue(newAmount, columnIndex, product);

      model.UpdateReplenishAmount(product.ID, newAmount);

  }
```

EDIT:

I am binding directly to the DataGridView datasource i.e.

`dataGridView.DataSource = BindingListView<Product>(products);`

Comment: How is the BindingLIstView exactly bound to the DataGridView. Do you use a BindingSource for this or do you directly bind to the BindingListView?

Comment: Btw, that technology is almost 10 yrs old. Why focus on that obsolete stuff instead of just creating underlying query with WHERE clause and binding it to DataTable or other data structures using .NET connection/command? Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently visible rows I have added the following method to my view

```
 public List<int> GetCurrentlyVisibleRowProductIDs()
 {
      List<int> productIDs = new List<int>();

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReplenish.Rows)
      {
              productIDs.Add((int)row.Cells[(int)ProductColumnIndex.ID].Value);

     }
    return productIDs;
 }
```

Then called this from my presenter, with a look up in the model for matching products

```
 private IList<Product> VisibleProducts()
 {
     var productsIDs = view.GetCurrentlyVisibleRowProductIDs();

     return model.GetProductsByID(productsIDs);
 }
```